# Is it possible to compile a different wireless chipset driver over the already available one on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wireless, driver, wireless-adapter

I have a fair amount of expertise in the field of setting up Wireless Ad-Hoc networks with Raspberry Pis. I currently am looking into the possibility of compiling a wireless driver over a preexisting, out-of-the-box driver for a USB dongle.

### Scenario

I have **LogiLink WL0145N** USB dongles of two types of chipsets:

- ones with `r8188eu` driver
- ones with `rt2x00lib` driver

From my observations I have found out that the Dongles with `r8188eu` drivers are notorious in joining an ad-hoc network. They also:

- do not let a user set the T<sub>x</sub> power using `iwconfig`
- do not let a user set the channel parameter using `iwconfig`
- Initially can be *ping*'d within the ad-hoc network and mysteriously **drop-out** of the network and become inaccessible.

So is it possible for instance, to remove the `r8188eu` drivers from the wireless chipset and compile the `rt2x00lib` in the Raspberry Pi?

If so are there some useful links or hints to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We as it turns out, compiling a wireless chipset driver is as follows:

1. make sure your system is up-to-date:

   ```
      sudo apt update
      sudo apt upgrade
      sudo dist-update
   ```
2. Install the **Kernel Header** for raspberry-pi as follows:

   ```
       sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
   ```
3. At this point whichever driver module you wish to install (if open source), clone to repository on you pi (here, we take [lwfinger rtl8188eu](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu))

   ```
       git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
       cd rtl8188eu
       make
       sudo make install
   ```

These steps are similar for most other firmware modules too.

#### Note

- Downloading the `raspberrypi-kernel-headers` will take a little time with no progress updates.
- [Source](https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000047172-how-to-install-ew-7611ulb-adapter-on-raspberry-pi)
- It is also worth observing that most of the the **Ralink** based firmware modules are already available with the the new **Jessie distro**. This can be observed using :

  ```
      sudo apt list firmware-ralink
  ```
- adding the `rt2x00lib` and/or `r8188eu` modules in the `/etc/modules` does not help changing wireless firmware for the USB dongle. As further tests show that the `r8188eu` dongles are still highly unreliable for ad-hoc functionality.
- adding `options r8188eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=1 rtw_ips_mode=1` in your `/etc/modprobe.d/8188eu.conf` does very little.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.